# OpenXml: Table of contents update giving Error! Bookmark not defined

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, tableofcontents

I am working on an OpenXml utility to dynamically add the content to a word document and then I want to update the table of contents.

```
        var byteTempArray = File.ReadAllBytes("Sample.docx");
        var _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        _memoryStream.Write(byteTempArray, 0, byteTempArray.Length);
        var _wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_memoryStream, true);
        var bodyDoc = _wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        SimpleField f = new SimpleField
        {
            Instruction = "sdtContent",
            Dirty = true
        };
        bodyDoc.AppendChild(f);
        _wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        _wordprocessingDocument.Close();
        File.WriteAllBytes(Guid.NewGuid()+".docx", _memoryStream.ToArray());
```

I have appended a SimpleField in the document with Dirty set to true. When I open the generated file, it shows below confirmation message to update the table of contents. Clicking on Yes updates the Table of Contents correctly.

[image]

But the issue is that **Error! Bookmark not defined.** text is appended at the bottom of doc.

Any idea how to remove this error message with table of contents update functionality working in place.

Comment: Did my answer help solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of what you are trying to do is to insert a dirty `w:fldSimple` element (`SimpleField` class) into your document to make Word update all fields, including the TOC, once the user opens that document with Microsoft Word. However, if you look at the Open XML markup produced by Microsoft Word after having updated the fields, you'll see that your `w:fldSimple` is the culprit.

I've created the following code to produce a straightforward Word document with (pretty much) just a field:

```
[Fact]
public void CheckBookmarkNotDefined()
{
    using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
        "SimpleField.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    MainDocumentPart part = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
    part.Document =
        new Document(
            new Body(
                new Paragraph(
                    new SimpleField
                    {
                        Instruction = "sdtContent",
                        Dirty = true
                    })));
}
```

The above code creates the following Open XML markup in the main document part:

```xml
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:fldSimple w:instr="sdtContent" w:dirty="true" />
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Note that the `w:fldSimple` element is contained in a `w:p` element (`Paragraph` class) as adding it to the `w:body` element (`Body` class) yields invalid Open XML markup.

Opening that document in Microsoft Word, updating the fields, and saving the document, makes Word create the following Open XML markup (which I've simplified a bit):

```xml
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>sdtContent</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
          <w:bCs/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Error! Bookmark not defined.</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr>
      [Child elements removed for clarity]
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

You can see that Word has turned the simple field (`w:fldSimple` element) into a complex field, using multiple `w:fldChar` elements and one `w:instrText` element having "sdtContent" as its content. Further, you can see the text "Error! Bookmark not defined." as the field's result.

Word creates that error message because your instruction text (`"sdtContent"`) is not correct. If you replace `"sdtContent"` with a valid field name such as `"AUTONUM"`, you will not see that error message. However, in the case of `AUTONUM`, you'd obviously get a visible field result. To avoid that, you could use a `REF` field, for which you need a valid bookmark, however. This is created in the following example:

```
[Fact]
public void CreateSimpleFieldForAutomaticUpdate()
{
    using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
        "SimpleFieldRef.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    MainDocumentPart part = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
    part.Document =
        new Document(
            new Body(
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Text("Hello World!"))),
                new BookmarkStart { Id = "32767", Name = "_RefUpdate" },
                new BookmarkEnd { Id = "32767" },
                new Paragraph(
                    new SimpleField
                    {
                        Instruction = "REF _RefUpdate",
                        Dirty = true
                    }),
                new SectionProperties()));
}
```

You'd have to write code to insert a `w:bookmarkStart` element (`BookmarkStart` class), a `w:bookmarkEnd` element (`BookmarkEnd` class), and `w:p` element with your `w:fldSimple` child element just before the `w:sectPr` element (`SectionProperties` class). In my example, I've used a large integer value as the bookmark id and `_RefUpdate` as the bookmark name, which is also used in the `Instruction` property.

Comment: Thank you. However, Word is still asking about updating the fields regardless of the validity of the instruction as soon as the field is dirty, and a quick web search confirmed that this is by design.

Comment: @Lucero, that is true. You can't avoid that dialog. I've once contemplated the mechanism leveraged by the OP but stayed away from it for that reason. It would be nice if one could make Word update fields such as TOCs and REFs since implementing that is quite a feat. For TOCs, for example, you need a layout engine to determine the page numbers. That alone is a **lot** of work.

Comment: I have implemented a Markdown to WordprocessingML converter (because I have plenty of Markdown which need to go into the document) and I implemented the `_Toc` bookmark generation on the headings, and a post-processing step which then generates the TOC just like Word does - but with empty page numbers, because that's indeed just too much work to get right. However, this gets rid of the dialog and the field usually gets updated when printing anyways, also just updating page numbers works fine, so I'm happy with the approach for now.

Comment: You have no idea how many headaches you just cured for me. I was trying to make figure numbers update sequentially, so I had to change "REF" to "SEQ" and it worked for me!